404 models/imagen-3.0-generate-001 is not found for API version v1beta
I'm trying to generate images using Google's Generative AI API, but I'm encountering a "NotFound" error. Here's my code:
import os
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key='my_api_key_here')
imagen = genai.ImageGenerationModel("imagen-3.0-generate-001")
result = imagen.generate_images(
    prompt="Fuzzy bunnies in my kitchen",
    number_of_images=4,
    safety_filter_level="block_only_high",
    person_generation="allow_adult",
    aspect_ratio="3:4",
    negative_prompt="Outside",
)

When I run this code, I get the following error:
File c:\Users\salos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py:76, in _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable(*args, **kwargs)
     75 try:
---> 76     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     77 except grpc.RpcError as exc:

File c:\Users\salos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py:1181, in _UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.__call__(self, request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression)
   1175 (
   1176     state,
   1177     call,
   1178 ) = self._blocking(
   1179     request, timeout, metadata, credentials, wait_for_ready, compression
   1180 )
-> 1181 return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)

File c:\Users\salos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py:1006, in _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, with_call, deadline)
   1005 else:
-> 1006     raise _InactiveRpcError(state)

_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.NOT_FOUND
    details = "models/imagen-3.0-generate-001 is not found for API version v1beta, or is not supported for predict. Call ListModels to see the list of available models and their supported methods."
    debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:142.250.182.138:443 {created_time:"2024-10-19T14:38:26.5900722+00:00", grpc_status:5, grpc_message:"models/imagen-3.0-generate-001 is not found for API version v1beta, or is not supported for predict. Call ListModels to see the list of available models and their supported methods."}"
>
...
     76     return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
     77 except grpc.RpcError as exc:
---> 78     raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc

NotFound: 404 models/imagen-3.0-generate-001 is not found for API version v1beta, or is not supported for predict. Call ListModels to see the list of available models and their supported methods.

I was following the code given in their official website: https://ai.google.dev/gemini-api/docs/imagen
I have also installed the beta version of Python SDK for the Gemini API (pip install -U git+https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python@imagen) and pillow as suggested in the guide.

This is the sample i use.
Two things to check.

That your api key was created in AI studio
That your API key is actually loading do a print on it.
At the time of writing the Imagen3 is not part of the main branch for the client library you need to install it directly from the image branch.

This is the branch you need.
# imagen GitHub branch: 
pip install -U git+https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python@imagen

code
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

load_dotenv()
genai.configure(api_key=os.environ['API_KEY'])


def read_text_from_file(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
        text = file.read()
    return text


# The stable version of Python SDK for the Gemini API does not contain Imagen support. Instead of installing the
# google-generativeai package from pypi you need to install it from the imagen GitHub branch: pip install -U
# git+https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-python@imagen


imagen = genai.ImageGenerationModel("imagen-3.0-generate-001")

result = imagen.generate_images(
    prompt=read_text_from_file("prompt.txt"),
    number_of_images=4,
    safety_filter_level="block_only_high",
    person_generation="allow_adult",
    aspect_ratio="16:9",
    negative_prompt="Outside",
)

for index, image in enumerate(result.images):
    # Open and display the image using your local operating system.
    image._pil_image.show()
    # Save the image using the PIL library's save function
    image._pil_image.save(f'image_{index}.jpg')

Note: i store my prompt in a the prompt.txt file locally you can just replace it with the prompt for your image.
404 Not found
At the time of writing this is still in early access and you must be whitelisted to use it.
This error message

NotFound: 404 models/imagen-3.0-generate-001 is not found for API version v1beta

If you are seeing that message it means you dont have access.
As you can see at the top of the documentation page

If you got an email saying you were whitelisted try to contact who ever white listed you.  If you are sure make sure that you used the white listed account to create the API key.
If you haven't been whitelisted you cant use it.  I'm not sure where you can apply for white list to this feature.  I can try to find out.

I have made the key in AI studio and printed it, it is showing my key and I even installed this in a virtual env, but still the same error is occurring. I copy pasted your code and made a prompt.txt also

And your sure you are using the account that was white listed for this feature?

If you could shed some information more about this, it would be helpful. I want to try this feature.

You need to apply to be white listed in order to test the beta features.   I just cant remember where you need to apply

I checked its not something that's open to everyone you have to be on a special list and there's no way to apply for it.   I have pushed back with a "But that's not fair"

Yes, Indeed. I wanted to try it so much. Imagen is available publicly in Gemini chat currently ;/

if you want to try vertex Imagen is available in that you dont need to be whitelisted.
